# Как доставать данные из html с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

В `body` имеется

```
<script> 
  // Google Analytics 
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){ 
    GoogleAnalyticsPurchase(JSON.parse('{"products:[{"id":111,"name":"test", "price":100,"qty":1},id":222,"name":"test1", "price":200,"qty":1}, "code":"1234567","costDelivery":0}')); 
  }); 
</script>
```

Каким образом, с помощью js, отсюда можно доставать (в виде текста) `id, name, price, qty` всех товаров (каждый раз разные)?

Answer (score 2):

Вы передаете в функцию по сути Js объект, почему нельзя раньше парсить его, и заносить в переменную, чтобы потом можно было к ней обращаться? По сути, вы должны обращаться к переменной.

```html
<script> 
  // Google Analytics 
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){ 
    var parseObject = JSON.parse('{"products:[{"id":111,"name":"test", "price":100,"qty":1},id":222,"name":"test1", "price":200,"qty":1}, "code":"1234567","costDelivery":0}');
   GoogleAnalyticsPurchase(parseObject); 
   alert(parseObject.id);//222
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**objParsed** - наш получаемый объект, я сделал такой, для примера.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadProps);

    function loadProps() {
        var objParsed = {"id":111,"name":"test","price":"222","qty":1};
        var objId = document.querySelector('.id');
        var objname = document.querySelector('.name');
        var objprice = document.querySelector('.price');
        var objqty = document.querySelector('.qty');
        objId.innerHTML = objParsed.id;
        objname.innerHTML = objParsed.name;
        objprice.innerHTML = objParsed.price;
        objqty.innerHTML = objParsed.qty;
    };

        <div class="div">Product</div>
        <p class="id"></p>
        <p class="name"></p>
        <p class="price"></p>
        <p class="qty"></p>
```

как-то так